# How to select same number of data points over different time ranges

Tags: postgresql

Grafana is querying our postgres database using this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
  tstamp AS "time"
  dvalue AS "weight"
FROM tablename
WHERE
  description = "exp_weight" AND
  tstamp BETWEEN 'time1' AND 'time2'
ORDER BY 
  tstamp
```

How can I code this such that I'm displaying the same number of data points even if my time intervals are different (ex. display 1,000 data points in the last hour or display 1,000 data points in the last month).

Comment: Randomly or how?

Comment: I would like for them to be ordered by tstamp which is a timestamp. Instead of taking every single timestamp and its associated weight, I only want 1,000 in order of time, spread evenly across the time range.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT tstamp AS time,
             dvalue AS weight
      FROM tablename
      WHERE description = 'exp_weight'
        AND tstamp BETWEEN 'time1' AND 'time2'
      ORDER BY random()
      LIMIT 1000
     ) AS q
ORDER BY time;
```

Explanation: The dataset is shuffled randomly, tgen the first 1000 values are taken and the result ordered by `time`. The subquery is just a syntactical necessity.

Comment: If I'm reading this solution correctly, this randomly samples data points in that time interval and limits the number of sampled points to 1,000?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for being too terse; I have added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it all except for the "AS q" part. Could you tell me what the purpose of that part is?

Comment: Just a technicality. Subqueries in `FROM` need an alias, even if it is never used.